# How to customize style of Toast window?

Tags: css, angular, angular6, primeng

The default size of a `<p-toast>` window is very small, and I would like to be able to adjust it, because my toast messages might be very long. I also need to be able to customize the style of the toast window as well, but I can't seem to get the CSS to work.

```
this.messageService.addAll([
  {key: 'tc', severity: 'info', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Very very very long task message to display number one that user needs to see blah blah blah'},
  {key: 'tc', severity: 'success', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Very very very long task message to display number two that needs to be bigger and more prominent'}
]);
```

I have tried a couple of methods based on the documentation.

**inline html**

```
<p-toast position="top-center" width="90%" key="tc"></p-toast>
```

**using ngStyle**

```
<p-toast position="top-center" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': '90%' }" key="tc"></p-toast>
```

**CSS in component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css'],
  styles: [`
    :host ::ng-deep .custom-toast .ui-toast-message {
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        background: #FFD07B;
    }` ],
  providers: [MessageService]
})


<p-toast position="top-center" style="custom-toast" key="tc"></p-toast>
```

**adding to style.css**

```
.custom-toast {
    width: 90%;
    background: #FFD07B;
}

:host ::ng-deep .custom-toast .ui-toast-message {
    width: 90%;
    background: #FFD07B;
}


<p-toast position="top-center" class="custom-toast" key="tc"></p-toast>
```

none of which worked.

Did I make a mistake somewhere in my syntax? How exactly do I adjust the style (color, font, especially the sizes) of the Toast window?

EDIT: Here is a [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hecboo) with all the stuff I've tried. Not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: have try to add `:host ::ng-deep .custom-toast .ui-toast-message` this in `style.css`

Comment: Yep, tried that. Edited my question to add to the list.

Comment: can you create `stackblitz`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after more tinkering, I finally figured out the solution. I needed to add an additional reference to the toast container in styles.css.

The html remains mostly the same.

```
<p-toast class="custom-toast"></p-toast>
```

**Styles.css** changed to add references to the toast container.

```
// centers the toast window to the middle of the screen
.custom-toast .ui-toast {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
}

// adjusts font, color and other elements of the toast window if needed
.custom-toast .ui-toast-message-content {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  background: #FFD07B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your '.ui-toast-message' class is of type 'display: block;'.
You first need to change it to 'display: flex;'

so your class may look something like

```
:host ::ng-deep .custom-toast .ui-toast-message {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px; // whatever width you need
}
```

and your angular code

```
<p-toast position="top-center" class="custom-toast" key="tc"></p-toast>
```

Edit: Working example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvbsr2)

Comment: `display: flex;` will cause multiple toasts to overlap however.

Comment: no using display: flex; wont overlap multiple toasts.

Comment: Apologies. They don't actually overlap but the toasts will be placed side by side without any margins. I need to keep the base functionality (toasts stacking on top of one another), but adjust the widths and other elements of the window.

Comment: I am looking in Chrome and i don't see toast placed side by side. It still see same functionality toast stacking on top of one another.

Comment: That's odd because I can't reproduce your example in my dev environment or in stackblitz. Here is [another stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6a1tv) to highlight my reply about the side-by-side toasts.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, please insert a style in your code like this

```
   <style>
        .ui.toast {
            width: 500px!important;
        }
    </style>
```

Remember all your toast will have this width, remove when not used.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.